# Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback()

Tags: forms, ajax

When using ajax for drop-down list, I receive the error message "Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback()". This comes from the Drupal core. What I noticed when debugging this error was that the 'triggering_element' is not the drop-down, but the form 'Submit' button. If I add another button before the 'Submit' button, it becomes the triggering_element.

Here is what I have as functionality:
Simple form with a button to 'Add drop-down'. When I click the button, a drop-down appears, but there is the problem with the '#ajax'. I want to be able to add more than one drop-down, and this is done, but for none of them the '#ajax' tag works.